# Experience Profile always shows anonymous or unknown as Name

Tags: experience-analytics, experience-profile

I'm creating a small POC to learning  Sitecore personalization, and I'm trying to create contacts.
I have a register form  where I will create extranet users and login form. 
The experience profile page always showing anonymous even I login also.
Then I try to identify contacts using this code after login code.

```cs
Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Session.Identify(UserName);
```

and I can see the current contact by

```cs
Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.Identifiers.Identifier
```

But when I look into  experience profile it is showing as "unknown" .

How this contacts make work?
Is there any detailed documentation available for it?

Sitecore Version : Sitecore.NET 8.2 (rev. 160729)

Comment: did you end the session or did you wait 20 minutes to end session automatically/

Comment: @SitecoreClimber I closed the browser window to end the session, But In the code I was not adding any value personal facet. Once I added those the name and other details began to show.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure what version of Sitecore you are on, but this is a bit of code from the Sitecore Launch site. It identifies the user and adds the out of the box xDB facets. This is Sitecore 8.1.0.151207.

```cs
    public static void SetVisitTagsOnLogin(string domainUser, bool IsNewUser)
    {
     string name = Sitecore.Context.User.Profile.FullName;
     if (name == String.Empty) name = Sitecore.Context.User.LocalName;
     Tracker.Current.Contact.Tags.Add("Username", domainUser);
     Tracker.Current.Contact.Tags.Add("Full name", name);

     Tracker.Current.Contact.Identifiers.AuthenticationLevel = AuthenticationLevel.PasswordValidated;
     Tracker.Current.Session.Identify(domainUser);

     if (IsNewUser)
     {
      IContactPersonalInfo personalFacet = Tracker.Current.Contact.GetFacet<IContactPersonalInfo>("Personal");
      personalFacet.FirstName = GetFirstName(name);
      personalFacet.Surname = GetSurName(name);

      IContactEmailAddresses addressesFacet = Tracker.Current.Contact.GetFacet<IContactEmailAddresses>("Emails");
      IEmailAddress address;
      if (!addressesFacet.Entries.Contains("work_email"))
      {
       address = addressesFacet.Entries.Create("work_email");
       address.SmtpAddress = GetEmailAddressFromUser(domainUser);
       addressesFacet.Preferred = "work_email";
      }
     }   
    }

    private static string GetFirstName(string fullname)
        {
         if (fullname.Contains(' '))
          return fullname.Substring(0, fullname.IndexOf(" "));

         return fullname;
        }

        private static string GetSurName(string fullname)
        {
         if (fullname.Contains(' '))
          return fullname.Substring(fullname.IndexOf(" ") + 1);

         return String.Empty;
        }

        private static string GetEmailAddressFromUser(string username)
        {
         if (username.Contains('\\'))
          return username.Substring(username.IndexOf("\\") + 1);

         return String.Empty;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, I found some other blogs related to this 
[link1](http://www.coreblimeysitecore.com/blog/sitecore-8-xdb-and-experience-profile-simplified)
[Link2](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Sitecore-Cookbook-For-Developers/blob/master/Chapter%2010/3.%20Storing%20visitor%20information%20in%20xDB%20contacts/Analytics/Helper/ContactHelper.cs)

Comment: Perfect. Could you please market my answer as answered if it solved your issue.