# Timeline always showing contact as unknown in Sitecore 9

Tags: experience-analytics, experience-profile

We have some code (in Sitecore 9.0.1) that identifies our contact (and saves some data in facets): `Tracker.Current.Session.IdentifyAs(IdentifierSource, email);`

I found this information on the new [docs](https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/tracking-and-session/tracker/tracking-contacts/identification/index.html). According to this [doc](https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-model/contacts/#known-and-anonymous-contacts) a contact is known as soon as it has at least one known identifier.

Our code sees to work. Our contact is saved to the database correctly and we can find it in the experience profile with all facets filled. Updates also work -
 the contact is recognized as being "not new" and updated accordingly.

In the `Xdb.Collection` database I can find my contact's identifier(s) with indeed the one with my source and `IdentifierType` 1. So that seems fine as well.

The problem is that although I can find my contact in the experience profile list & details (with everything filled perfectly), the timeline (also showing correct data) still says it is an *unknown* contact.

I did check the "internet" and found this [answer](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2219/experience-profile-always-shows-anonymous-or-unknown-as-name) on SSE (where else..), but that is for 8.2 and doesn't seem to be the solution for v9.

Does anyone know how to get a Sitecore 9 to show "known contact"?

Comment: this has been in my backlog for a while. I don't think it's specific to 9, as I have an 8.2U5 site doing the same thing.

Comment: Me too, but I was mentioning the version explicitely because I noticed that people seem to have this fixed in 8 versions (even an answered question here)

Comment: Btw, I heard a rumour that this behavior is intentional..  which doesn't make sense to me but if that can be explained, I'm willing to here that explanation

Comment: Corey Smith did a deep dive on Eras, which is really what this is targeting and blogged about it for Sitecore 8, but... this definitely used to switch from anonymous to known eras.  If intentional, would love to know the reasoning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research I managed to find my answer..

I was told:

> The label is intended to show "unknown contact" at the beginning of
>   the life-time of a given contact. Additional areas will be populated
>   when the contact registers any outcome.

But this is only half correct. I tried registering an outcome as well as identifying my contact and although I could see the outcome, still no change in the "unknown contact" label. Then I found this magnificent blog post describing it all.. apparently you need to select the right outcome group (`Lead management funnel`) with your outcome to make it trigger a new era. As soon as I did that, it worked..

Now I just need to find a way to trigger that outcome only once.. but that is [another question](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/10387/237).

All the info on this can be found on: https://www.coreysmith.co/sitecore-xdb-custom-eras-in-experience-profile-timeline/ (thx Corey!)