# Outcome ignore additional registrations in Sitecore 9

Tags: experience-profile, outcomes

I was following this awesome blogpost on outcomes https://www.coreysmith.co/sitecore-xdb-custom-eras-in-experience-profile-timeline/  I created an outcome and all seems to work fine, but I should have a field `Ignore Additional Registrations`. I want to use it in order to make sure the outcome isn't registered multiple times.

I can find that field in Sitecore 8, but in Sitecore 9 I'm not seeing it.. I see some other new checkboxes, but not this one.

Is there another way to make sure an outcome isn't registered twice (or more) in Sitecore 9?

Comment: Is the outcome being registered programmatically?

Comment: Yes it is. But can't find a simple option there either.

Comment: Then why not checking if the outcome has already been registered by the user, do not trigger it again?

Comment: In 8 there was an ootb option.. so hoping to have the same in 9.

Comment: Ok best thing to do is to contact sitecore support about it to know if it has been removed or not. But as a workaround, you can have a check if the outcome is present in either the current interaction or behaviorCache via code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted Sitecore support and they had the documentation updated. It now states:

> `AdditionalRegistrationsAreIgnored` was used by the `OutcomeManager` and
>   is no longer in use. Please remove this property from your code.

So there is no ootb option for this anymore. You can write this functionality yourself but be aware that other code might still register the outcome through xConnect.

Comment: With xConnect it is pretty easy to check whether there was an outcome triggered for that particular contact. Follow this doc article -> https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-client-api/contacts/get-contacts/get-contact-interactions.html#filtering-interactions

Comment: So before triggering outcome, just check in your custom code whether you haven't already triggered it. That's it!